# What is the recommended max level of heap memory usage? Recommended garbage collection time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, alarm

I recently found that one of my services was taking a large amount of time in garbage collection because the max heap size was too small.  The service was there before I started, so I was unaware of the low heap size. I would like to set an alarm to warn me if it goes back up past a certain point, but I also do not want to give it more resources than it actually needs.  What do you think is a reasonable level to be alarmed about for garbage collection and percent heap used?

I was thinking that an alarm on average heap usage would be ~85 percent, and 100 ms of gc / 5 min.

I understand this is based on requirements and hardware, but I am really looking for some benchmark or standard upon which to make my decision.

Comment: This depends entirely on the context and program you have written... the recommended "max level" of heap memory usage and recommended GC time is *as little as possible*. :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood I would consider that comment to be an answer, and the correct answer.  Too bad I can't upvote it and give you the rep.

Comment: The JVM will typically reach 99%+ heap usage before it GCs. Only the percentage used after a Full GC matters and that should be about 30-50% IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alex Lockwood's answer says this:

> The recommended "max level" of heap memory usage and GC time is *as little as possible*.

That is misleading.  I'd actually advise the reverse.  It is a bad idea to try to squeeze the heap size, because that will lead to your application running the GC more frequently, and spending less time (on average) doing useful work.

The problem is basically this.  The classical (non-concurrent) GC gets run when the JVM runs out of space to allocate objects.  It then traverses the non-garbage objects, copying them to a different "space".  The processor time to run a GC cycle is most strongly dependent on the amount of non-garbage ... but the useful work it achieves (the amount of space it releases) is proportional to `heapsize - nongarbage`.  So when you squeeze the heapsize, you decrease the amount of useful work that the GC does ... for the same processor time expenditure.

The original question says this:

> I was thinking that an alarm on average heap usage would be ~85 percent, and 100 ms of gc / 5 min.

It is probably not useful to set a monitor / alarm on an absolute level of GC CPU usage.  GC time will depend on server activity as well as GC efficiency.  You don't want the GC alarm to go off every time your server gets busy.

An average heap usage of 85% is reasonable level to be alarming at, though once again setting an alarm at a fixed level might give too many false alarms.

An alternative to this is to use the JVM options to set a "percentage time spent in GC" threshold, and combine that with the "kill JVM on OutOfMemoryException" option, and put a auto-restart loop in the server's launch scripts.  Then monitor for restarts.

Comment: I believe that saying garbage collection is proportional to `heapsize - nongarbage` is only half true. I'm fairly confident Java uses a mixed stop-and-copy + generational garbage collector, in which case that statement isn't entirely accurate. But then again, I'm just being nitpicky over here. Other than that, I'd have to agree with your answer over Alex's.

Comment: You are mixing up your GC terminology.  Concurrent versus Stop-the-world is about whether the GC runs in the background or not.  Copying versus mark-and-sweep is about the family of algorithm that is runs.  And generational is about whether you GC the whole heap at the same rate, or spend more time collection the young objects.

Comment: But you are right, a modern Hotspot JVM does use a mixture of strategies, including (I believe) mark-and-sweep if there isn't enough space for a big enough "to" space.  Even so, the work is more strongly related to the amount of non-garbage when you factor in a compaction phase.  (And I'm sure it must do mark-sweep-compact otherwise the heap allocator has to deal with free lists.)

Comment: Poor wording on my end. I should have been more explicit. I was referring to the method of using the copying algorithm while using the generational strategy to avoid looking at old objects as often. The point I was trying to get at is that, if memory is dominated by old objects and the collector uses a generational strategy, time spent in garbage collection won't always be proportional to `heapsize - nongarbage`

Comment: No you are right.  It should be "spacesize - nongarbage".  But the spacesize is related to the heapssize ... and directly related if you are doing a "full" collection.

Comment: I meant 85% averaged over a 5 minute period which means it could go above that and not alarm, but if it goes above that and stays enough to push the average over 85%.  I'm not worried about sudden spikes as much as a gradual increase over time as the application requires more resources.

Comment: Well, I'm certainly not going to argue with you... you obviously know a lot more about this than I do :). I didn't mean to suggest that the heap size needed to be as small as possible (and I actually didn't even think it would be interpreted that way until now). My answer was more suggesting "don't worry about the benchmark... worry about implementing your code correctly so that you don't abuse the GC/heap." It's certainly not as detailed as your answer, but hopefully you can agree with that at least. Thanks for teaching me something tonight though... I didn't know about some of this stuff :).